# How to mock a Python class to change just one argument

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

I need to wrap a class in a mock like so:

Original code:

```
class _InnerImpl(object):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # do stuff
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

def my_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  kwargs['arg1'] = gen_next_value()  # change one of the arguments
  return _InnerImpl(*args, **kwargs)  # call the real thing with modified args

def run(user_input):
  with patch(_InnerImpl, my_wrapper):
     some_method(user_input)
```

Unfortunately the way that `patch` works, I can't call the "real thing" because it is also called inside the `with patch` block. This results in infinite recursion loop.

I'm using this in an implementation outside of unit test. So this isn't for unit tests. I've tried various things such as saving `__init__` reference, using `wraps`. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using mocks for things that aren't unit tests. If I understand your example, it seems like what you need is a Factory method pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

If you can't modify the code you are patching, try using a different namespace. e.g., given target code `a.py`

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        print('A({})'.format(v))

def foo():
    y = A('a')
```

you could write `b.py`

```
from unittest.mock import patch
from a import A,foo
def my_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    return A('b')
def bar():
    with patch('a.A', my_wrapper):
        foo()
```

Comment: In this case, I don't own the underlying code nor can I change the user-facing interface. So the only option I have is to intercept the call in the middle.

Comment: Possibly then the answer is to make use of the information here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch and to do an import into another namespace `b` prior to patching in namespace `a`. Then the `b` namespace version will still point to the original.